# 2sxc - undefined 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, console.log, 2sxc

I'm using DNN version 7.3.4 and 2sxc version 8.12.0.

I'm experiencing an error in browser console saying 
**GET .../Images/undefined 404 (Not Found)**

Then, I saw the error in jquery.js file as below:
jquery.js?cdv=137:7152
and it says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

It would be great if you explain what is the reason behind of this error?

Note: 2sxc module works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with your template, and not with 2sxc - as it looks like something is trying to load an image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Yes, that was issue with DNN skin file and I resolved that by creating new skin for that page.